# Getting Enum type from string of chars

Tags: c#, string, enums, enumeration

I've looked at similar questions but they don't seem to be dealing with the same issue I'm having.

I have an enum for CRUD permission testing defined as

```
public enum CRUDOperation
    {
        NotNeeded = 0,
        Read = 1,
        Create = 2,
        Update = 4,
        Delete = 8
    }
```

I didn't write this next part of code which is why I might be confused, but then the CRUD permission values associated with a role are put into a "Restrictions" string in the following manner.

```
            Restrictions = "";
            foreach (string inCrud in restrictions)
            {
                string crud = inCrud.ToUpper();
                int res = 0;
                if (crud.Contains('C'))
                    res |= (char)CRUDOperation.Create;
                if (crud.Contains('R'))
                    res |= (char)CRUDOperation.Read;
                if (crud.Contains('U'))
                    res |= (char)CRUDOperation.Update;
                if (crud.Contains('D'))
                    res |= (char)CRUDOperation.Delete;
                Restrictions += (char)res;
            }
```

And now I need to parse through this "Restrictions" string to check if a given role has the appropriate CRUDOperation permission levels. However the string is full of random ascii characters and I'm just having a hard time understanding how to do this correctly. I haven't worked with bitmasks really at all before. I'm trying to do this;

```
CRUDOperation operation = (CRUDOperation)Enum.Parse(typeof(CRUDOperation), p.Restrictions);
```

but i'm getting the error "Requested value '            ' was not found."

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: This seems like a very confusing way to do something very simple.

Comment: I'm not sure that the second piece of code does what the original author *thinks* it does. This would be a lot easier with the `Flags` attribute...

Comment: so what is it doing exactly? my impression of what's happening is it's either adding a 0 or the char conversion of the enum value to the restrictions string?

Comment: When you are converting the enum value to char you are getting the char 0 ( non printable char) from ASCII table and not a character representing 0 which is 48 on ASCII table. And also, I agree with @Icemanind, this code is overcomplicated.

Comment: i agree that it's over complicated as well, but i feel that way about a lot of the code i see and so i just defer to the better coder's judgments, one of whom wrote the code in question. so what would you do if you were me to solve this issue? or to try and achieve what my goal is?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call the person that wrote this a "better coder".

Comment: What exactly is `restrictions`? Can you post an example how that variable is being assigned?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in that code is that when you do this: `Restrictions += (char)res;` you are actually adding the character whose code is the result of your operation. The resulting Restrictions string can't be parsed as an enum.

I'm not sure why Restrictions is kept as a string. I would change the type of Restrictions to CRUDOperation and replace the first bit of code with this:

```
 Restrictions = CRUDOperation.None;
 foreach (string inCrud in restrictions)
 {
     string crud = inCrud.ToUpper();
     int res = 0;
     if (crud.Contains('C'))
        Restrictions |= CRUDOperation.Create;
     if (crud.Contains('R'))
        Restrictions |= CRUDOperation.Read;
     if (crud.Contains('U'))
        Restrictions |= CRUDOperation.Update;
     if (crud.Contains('D'))
        Restrictions |= CRUDOperation.Delete;
 }
```

This way you have the result directly.

If for some reason you have to have a string with the result you need to use a separator for the values you are adding: `Restrictions += " " + (int)res;` After that you can parse the string by splitting it and then parsing it (make sure to remove any empty entries before parsing).

Answer (score 0):

Before answering the question, I just want to point out that this is a crappy way of doing things. But I'm assuming you were inherited the code and you can't change it. But just keep in mind, code shouldn't work like this. The better way to do it is storing it in a `List<CRUDOperation>` instead of just concatenating it all to a string.

Okay now for your answer. Near as I can tell, what this code seems to be doing is building a string up of `enum` values. So if the code looked like this:

```
String Restrictions = "";
string[] restrictions = {"U", "C", "R"};

foreach (string inCrud in restrictions)
{
    string crud = inCrud.ToUpper();
    int res = 0;
    if (crud.Contains('C'))
        res |= (char)CRUDOperation.Create;
    if (crud.Contains('R'))
        res |= (char)CRUDOperation.Read;
    if (crud.Contains('U'))
        res |= (char)CRUDOperation.Update;
    if (crud.Contains('D'))
        res |= (char)CRUDOperation.Delete;
    Restrictions += (char)res;
}
```

This would build up a string of characters unreadable characters that contains this:

```
0x04, 0x02, 0x01
```

So if what you are needing to do is determine if someone has permissions based on this string, you can do something like this:

```
bool hasReadPermission = HasCrudPermission(Restrictions, CRUDOperation.Read);
bool hasCreatePermission = HasCrudPermission(Restrictions, CRUDOperation.Create);
bool hasUpdatePermission = HasCrudPermission(Restrictions, CRUDOperation.Update);
bool hasDeletePermission = HasCrudPermission(Restrictions, CRUDOperation.Delete);

    private bool HasCrudPermission(string restrictions, CRUDOperation permission)
    {
       return restrictions.Any(c => HasCrudPermission(c, permission));
    }

    private bool HasCrudPermission(char restriction, CRUDOperation permission)
    {
        return ((CRUDOperation)restriction) == permission;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the response. this seems to make the most sense so i tried implementing it, but for some reason it's just returning false for everything except for "Read" no matter what. not sure why.

Comment: Is `restrictions` structured like I have it: `string[] restrictions = {"U", "C", "R"};`?